# How to add missing "Embedded Binaries" section within Xcode project > TARGETS for the.Net Embedding HELLO WORLD

Tags: c#, .net, xcode, xamarin, embeddinator

I need to add hello-from-csharp.framework to TARGETS > General tab's > Embedded Binary section, which is not there.

I'm following the MICROSOFT > DOCS > Getting started with iOS > hello-from-csharp C# example for converting a HELLO WORLD C# class lib into Xcode ObjC

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Embedded Binary section has been renamed to Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content, which is at the bottom of your screenshot.